# Enable lua and caps for use with rpm

Tags: linux, package-management, rpm

I wish to install `qemu-kvm` on my Wind River Linux system, using `dnf`, however, I run into this error -

```
rpmlib(BuiltInLuaScripts) <= 4.2.2-1 is needed by filesystem-3.10-1.fc30.x86_64
rpmlib(FileCaps) <= 4.6.1-1 is needed by shadow-utils-2:4.6-8.fc30.x86_64
```

I am not certain if these are features that needed to be enabled in my system someplace, or are separate packages that need to be installed, or `rpm` needs to be built with these.

Answer (score 0):

These dependencies are "virtual" dependencies provided by the `rpm` library. It would seem that the package that you are trying to install was packaged for a different version of `rpm`.

Comment: Doing a `rpm --showrc | grep rpmlib` does not list down `caps` or `lua` related libraries at all. Would the issue be resolved if these packages can be enabled somehow, or, short of building `kvm` against the currently installed `rpm` version, this is unrecoverable? I am not using`Fedora 30` as a repository, is there a place where I can find a `kvm` package built for specific `rpm` versions?

Comment: in any case you should try to find `rpm` package on a distribution as similar as possible to yours, otherwise you might always run into problems like this. you can try searching here: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I am new to `Linux`, may I know what it is that indicates similarity between various distributions? Perhaps kernel version and package management? I chose `Fedora` since it had `rpm` and `dnf`, which I have on my distro as well. I know these are different from `apt-get` and `debian` style package managements, but is there anything else, which i can use to check compatibility?

Comment: did you add the repository containing qemu-kvm yourself? If so, is it the repository for fedora30 (or whatever your exact version is)? If no that is where your problems come from.

Comment: I have a very locked down /restricted version of Linux, I'm not sure which distribution it is most similar to, since it had `rpm`, `dnf`, I imagined it'd be similar to `Red Hat` / `CentOs` /  `Fedora` packages, so I set the `dnf` repository to Fedora-30 repository archive and tried to pull `qemu-kvm` from there using `dnf install`. That's where I ran into the problem with `rpmlib` described above.